# Crear botón de regresar en python

Tags: python, botón

Hola estoy intentando hacer un botón pero me manda un error tengo 2 ventanas la principal y la secundaria cuando pulso el botón para ver la ventana secundaria destruyo la principal para que solo se vea la segunda ahora al momento de volver a la ventana principal no puedo creo una función donde al pulsar el botón de regresar destruya esa ventana y me muestre la principal pero no funciona me podrían ayudar porfa. No se como hacerlo de otra manera estoy aprendiendo pero no encontre de que manera se hace.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import font

ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.title("SISECOVE")
ventana.geometry("800x500+350+200")
ventana.resizable(0,0)

def admin():
    user1 = tkinter.Tk()
    user1.title("Administrador")
    user1.geometry("500x500+500+200")
    user1.resizable(0,0)
    ventana.destroy()

    a_boton1= tkinter.Button(user1, text="Ingresar")
    a_boton1.place(x=220,y=300)

    a_boton2=tkinter.Button(user1, text="Regresar", command=atras)
    a_boton2.place(x=220, y=400)

    t_user=Entry(user1)
    t_user.place(x=180, y=100)
    l_user=tkinter.Label(user1, text="USUARIO:")
    l_user.place(x=210, y=70)

    t_pass=Entry(user1)
    t_pass.place(x=180, y=200)
    l_pass=tkinter.Label(user1,text="CONTRASEÑA:")
    l_pass.place(x=200, y=170)

def salir():
    ventana.destroy()

def encarg():
    user2 = tkinter.Tk()
    user2.title("Encargado")
    user2.geometry("500x500+500+200")
    user2.resizable(0,0)
    ventana.destroy()

    e_a_boton1= tkinter.Button(user2, text="Ingresar")
    e_a_boton1.place(x=220,y=300)

    e_a_boton2=tkinter.Button(user2, text="Regresar")
    e_a_boton2.place(x=220, y=400)

    e_t_user=Entry(user2)
    e_t_user.place(x=180, y=100)
    e_l_user=tkinter.Label(user2, text="USUARIO:")
    e_l_user.place(x=210, y=70)

    e_t_pass=Entry(user2)
    e_t_pass.place(x=180, y=200)
    e_l_pass=tkinter.Label(user2,text="CONTRASEÑA:")
    e_l_pass.place(x=200, y=170)

etiqueta1 = tkinter.Label(ventana, text= "SISECOVE", font=("Arial", 18))
etiqueta1.place(x=330, y=20)

boton1 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Administrador", command= admin)
boton1.place(x=300,y=220)

boton2 = tkinter.Button(ventana,text="Encargado", command= encarg)
boton2.place(x=400,y=220)

boton3 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Salir", command= salir)
boton3.place(x=720,y=420)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: _Me manda un error_: ¿cuál error? Pulsa en [edit] y ponlo en la pregunta. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca elimines una ventana u objeto principal en Tkinter, lo mejor que puedes hacer con la ventana principal 'ventana', es simplemente ocultarla, y creas la secundaria que sea hija de la principal, asi cuando quieras volver, destruyes la secundaria y vuelves a mostrar la principal. Si necesitas que te lo explique mejor me lo dices, pero esta bastante claro. Saludos.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import font

ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.title("SISECOVE")
ventana.geometry("800x500+350+200")
ventana.resizable(0, 0)


def atras(ventana_a_cerrar):
    ventana_a_cerrar.destroy()
    ventana.deiconify()


def admin():
    user1 = tkinter.Toplevel(ventana)
    user1.title("Administrador")
    user1.geometry("500x500+500+200")
    user1.resizable(0, 0)
    # ventana.destroy() No la destruyas, mejor ocultala
    ventana.withdraw()# Ocultala

    a_boton1 = tkinter.Button(user1, text="Ingresar")
    a_boton1.place(x=220, y=300)

    a_boton2 = tkinter.Button(user1, text="Regresar", command=lambda: atras(user1))
    a_boton2.place(x=220, y=400)

    t_user = Entry(user1)
    t_user.place(x=180, y=100)
    l_user = tkinter.Label(user1, text="USUARIO:")
    l_user.place(x=210, y=70)

    t_pass = Entry(user1)
    t_pass.place(x=180, y=200)
    l_pass = tkinter.Label(user1, text="CONTRASEÑA:")
    l_pass.place(x=200, y=170)


def salir():
    ventana.destroy()


def encarg():
    user2 = tkinter.Tk()
    user2.title("Encargado")
    user2.geometry("500x500+500+200")
    user2.resizable(0, 0)
    # ventana.destroy() No la destruyas
    ventana.withdraw() # Ocultala

    e_a_boton1 = tkinter.Button(user2, text="Ingresar")
    e_a_boton1.place(x=220, y=300)

    e_a_boton2 = tkinter.Button(user2, text="Regresar",command=lambda: atras(user2))
    e_a_boton2.place(x=220, y=400)

    e_t_user = Entry(user2)
    e_t_user.place(x=180, y=100)
    e_l_user = tkinter.Label(user2, text="USUARIO:")
    e_l_user.place(x=210, y=70)

    e_t_pass = Entry(user2)
    e_t_pass.place(x=180, y=200)
    e_l_pass = tkinter.Label(user2, text="CONTRASEÑA:")
    e_l_pass.place(x=200, y=170)


etiqueta1 = tkinter.Label(ventana, text="SISECOVE", font=("Arial", 18))
etiqueta1.place(x=330, y=20)

boton1 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Administrador", command=admin)
boton1.place(x=300, y=220)

boton2 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Encargado", command=encarg)
boton2.place(x=400, y=220)

boton3 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Salir", command=salir)
boton3.place(x=720, y=420)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono no sabia que no podía destruir la ventana principal de ahora en adelante la ocultare solamente

Comment: @BrayanPerezContreras si la respuesta te ha ayudado y resuelve el problema podrías marcarla como aceptada :)