# problema al generar nueva ventana tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

quiero diseñar un programa, con tkinter, que:

con un boton cierre la ventana actual (pantalla principal) y abra una nueva, con eso no tengo inconveniente. el problema es que en la nueva ventana quiero que haya un boton que sea como un volver o salir a la pantalla principal. pense en while, pero no funciono. me pueden ayudar?

gracias

edit:
logre realizar lo de las ventanas, pero ahora me desaparecieron los botones, asi que basicamente, no puedo volver a la ventana original, ni cerrar, ni nada

###########################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import INSERT, ttk,messagebox
import time, sqlite3, requests
try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect("comercio.sqlite")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Registro (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Encargado TEXT, Fecha TEXT, Evento TEXT, Caja REAL)")
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Ventas (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Cliente TEXT, Fecha TEXT, Combo_S INT, Combo_D INT, Combo_T INT, Flurby INT, Total REAL)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    pass
caja_total = 0
def Cerrar_Programa():
    exit()
def Logout(x):
    fecha = time.asctime()
    if messagebox.askyesno("ADVERTENCIA","¿Desea cerrar sesion?"):
        evento = "OUT"
        conn = sqlite3.connect("comercio.sqlite")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Registro VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)",(encargado,fecha,evento,caja_total))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        x.destroy()
        ventana_ppal.deiconify()
        a = caja_encargado.get()
        caja_encargado.delete(0,tk.END)
        messagebox.showinfo("AVISO",f"{a} ha cerrado la\nsesion correctamente")
        caja_total = 0
def Cancelar_Pedido(caja_combo_s,caja_combo_d,caja_combo_t,caja_flurby,caja_cliente):
    caja_combo_s.delete(0,tk.END)
    caja_combo_d.delete(0,tk.END)
    caja_combo_t.delete(0,tk.END)
    caja_flurby.delete(0,tk.END)
    caja_cliente.delete(0,tk.END)

def Login():
    fecha = time.asctime()
    evento = "IN"
    global encargado
    encargado = caja_encargado.get()   
    if encargado == "":
        messagebox.showwarning("ADVERTENCIA","ESCRIBIR UN USUARIO")
    else:
        conn = sqlite3.connect("comercio.sqlite")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Registro VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)",(encargado,fecha,evento,caja_total)) 
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        Ventana_menu_pedidos()
def Dolar():
    r = requests.get("http://api-dolar-argentina.herokuapp.com/api/dolaroficial")
    a =r.json()
    dolar = a["venta"]
    return dolar
def Hacer_Pedido(combo_s,combo_d,combo_t,flurby,cliente):
    global caja_total
    fecha = time.asctime()
    try:
        combo_s = int(combo_s.get())
        combo_d = int(combo_d.get())
        combo_t = int(combo_t.get())
        flurby = int(flurby.get())
        total_dolares = float((combo_s*5)+(combo_d*6)+(combo_t*7)+(flurby*2))
        dolar = Dolar()
        total_pesos = total_dolares*dolar
        if messagebox.askokcancel("verificar info",f"¿Desea procesar el pedido:\n${total_pesos}"):
            conn = sqlite3.connect("comercio.sqlite")
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Ventas VALUES(null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(cliente,fecha,combo_s,combo_d,combo_t,flurby,total_pesos))
            caja_total += total_pesos
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
    except ValueError:
        return messagebox.showerror("ADVERTENCIA","Ingresar solo valores numericos\n en las cantidades")    
def Ventana_menu_pedidos():
    a = caja_encargado.get()
    ventana_menu = tk.Tk()
    ventana_menu.title("Pedidos")
    ventana_menu.geometry("600x400")
    ventana_ppal.withdraw()
    # etiquetas menu
    et_menu_pedidos = ttk.Label(ventana_menu,text="""HamburguesasIT
Encargad@
Recuerda, siempre hay que recibir al cliente
con una sonrisa :)""")
    et_menu_pedidos.place(y=20,x=150)
    et_encargado = ttk.Label(ventana_menu,text="Encargado:")
    et_encargado.place(x=110,y=90)
    et_combo_s = ttk.Label(ventana_menu,text="Combo S:")
    et_combo_s.place(x=110,y=120)
    et_combo_d = ttk.Label(ventana_menu,text="Combo D:")
    et_combo_d.place(x=110,y=150)
    et_combo_t = ttk.Label(ventana_menu,text="Combo T:")
    et_combo_t.place(x=110,y=180)
    et_flurby = ttk.Label(ventana_menu,text="Flurby:")
    et_flurby.place(x=110,y=210)
    et_cliente = ttk.Label(ventana_menu,text="Cliente:")
    et_cliente.place(x=110,y=240)
    # casillas
    caja_encargado_pedido = ttk.Entry(ventana_menu)
    caja_encargado_pedido.insert(0,a)
    caja_encargado_pedido.config(state="readonly")
    caja_encargado_pedido.place(x=200,y=90)    
    caja_combo_s =  ttk.Entry(ventana_menu)
    caja_combo_s.place(x=200,y=120)
    caja_combo_d =  ttk.Entry(ventana_menu)
    caja_combo_d.place(x=200,y=150)
    caja_combo_t =  ttk.Entry(ventana_menu)
    caja_combo_t.place(x=200,y=180)
    caja_flurby =  ttk.Entry(ventana_menu)
    caja_flurby.place(x=200,y=210)
    caja_cliente =  ttk.Entry(ventana_menu)
    caja_cliente.place(x=200,y=240)
    cliente = caja_cliente.get()
    combo_s = int(caja_combo_s.get())
    combo_d = int(caja_combo_d.get())
    combo_t = int(caja_combo_t.get())
    flurby = int(caja_flurby.get())
    # botones
    hacer_pedido = ttk.Button(ventana_menu,text="Hacer Pedido",command=lambda: Hacer_Pedido(combo_s,combo_d,combo_t,flurby,cliente))
    hacer_pedido.place(x=330,y=300)
    cancelar_pedido = ttk.Button(ventana_menu,text="Cancelar Pedido",command=lambda: Cancelar_Pedido(caja_combo_s,caja_combo_d,caja_combo_t,caja_flurby,caja_cliente))
    cancelar_pedido.place(x=200,y=300)    
    logout = ttk.Button(ventana_menu,text="Cerrar Sesion",command=lambda: Logout(ventana_menu))
    logout.place(x=100,y=300)
#parte grafica ventana principal
ventana_ppal = tk.Tk()
ventana_ppal.title("Menu Principal")
ventana_ppal.geometry("500x300")
# etiqueta
etiqueta_ventana_ppal = ttk.Label(ventana_ppal,text= """Bienvenido a Hamburguesas IT
Ingrese su nombre encargad@: """)
etiqueta_ventana_ppal.place(x=80,y=60)
#caja de encargado
caja_encargado = ttk.Entry(ventana_ppal)
caja_encargado.place(x=250,y=75)
#botones
cerrar_programa = ttk.Button(ventana_ppal,text="Cerrar Programa",command=Cerrar_Programa)
cerrar_programa.place(x=280,y=250)
login_encargado = ttk.Button(text="Login",command=Login)
login_encargado.place(x=140,y=250)
ventana_ppal.mainloop()
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir un ejemplo del código que estas utilizando? Te recomiendo que mires esta publicación, trata lo mismo de lo que estas hablando: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/513372/crear-botón-de-regresar-en-python/513433#513433

Comment: me sirvio muchisimo, puse un edit

Comment: ya encontre la solucion, las funciones de las cuales acuden los botones en la 2da ventana, deben estar anidadas dentro de esa funcion. gracias